# antd table, disable unsorted option for a column (force sort)

Tags: reactjs, antd

To enable sort on a column, using the `sortDirections` parameter with values `['ascend', 'descend']`. With this setting there are 3 sorting options: 'ascend', 'descend', 'unsorted'.

Is there a simple way to force sorting, remove the unsorted option?

For example:

Given a list of unsorted numbers [1, 5 ,2 ,10] . Currently, I can set `sortDirections` with values `['ascend', 'descend']`. This will provide 3 options, sort in ascending order, sort in descended order AND unsorted, e.g. same as the original numbers.

Desired behavior:

I would like to force sort, meaning I don't want the 'unsorted' option to be available. If the user clicks the column header, the whole column should be sorted either in ascending order or in descended order.

Comment: Example?... Input example and desired output? What does it mean "remove the unsorted option"

Comment: @DennisVash, input a list of unsorted numbers [1, 5 ,2 ,10] . Currently, I can set sortDirections with values ['ascend', 'descend']

As I described, this will provide 3 options, sort in ascending order, sort in descended order AND unsorted, e.g. same as the original numbers. 

Desired behavior: I would like to force sort, meaning I don't want the 'unsorted' option to be available. If the user click the column header the whole column should be sorted either in ascending order or in descended order.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head) but actually helpful.

> "You can set as ['ascend', 'descend', 'ascend'] to prevent sorter back to default status."

Comment: I tested this on my site and it does seem to work. You'll want to make sure you have a default sort order as well using the prop ```defaultSortOrder: 'ascend',```

Comment: lol that is NOT clear. Should say "...to disable unsorted option" or something. However, it would probably make more sense to just have a third option called "unsorted" and let people leave it out when they want.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-head):

> `sortDirections: ['ascend' | 'descend']` defines available sort methods for each columns, effective for all columns when set on table props.

Comment: Thanks.. links right to where I needed to go

Answer (score 0):

I've been poking around too and there is no way (as of now) of customizing the column header sorting behavior to ignore the unsorted state. Moreover, the developers clearly state that they want to sticky with this way here:

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12905

@mkkekkonen make sure you used the docs before pointing to it...

Answer (score 0):

I have recently wanted similar behavior, and I did the following and it works fine.

```
const [sort, setSort] = useState('ascend');

{
      title: 'Age',
      dataIndex: 'age',
      key: 'age',
      sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
      sortOrder: sort,
      onHeaderCell: () => ({
        onClick: () => setSort(sort === 'ascend' ? 'descend' : 
      'ascend'),       
      sortDirections: ['ascend', 'descend', 'ascend'],
      }),
},
```